# Why is S_ISDIR() indicating a directory when there isn't one?

Tags: c++, filesystems, posix, cout, stat

The POSIX function [S_ISDIR](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html) is occasionally lying to me.
It's telling me that a directory exists, when it clearly doesn't.

Here is a small program that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  std::cout << lstat(path_to_file, &fileInfo) << " ";
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}

int main(){

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Directory("folder") << '\n';
}
```

If I run this program (a lot of times), very quickly, I will see the following output:

```
$./main
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
$./main
-1 false
-1 false
-1 true
-1 true
-1 true
-1 true
$./main
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
-1 false
```

See how the function suddenly returns `true`, even though the directory doesn't exist.

What's strange though, is that if I put the program in an infinite loop of checking, it will continue to say that the directory does not exist.  It's only by running the program again and again in rapid succession do I spot the issue.

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

**check the code:** 
The code doesn't seem wrong.

```
Macro: int S_ISDIR (mode_t m)   
This macro returns non-zero if the file is a directory.
```

The error code of `lstat` is always -1 so I don't think there is an occasional error populating stat.

**read documentation:** 
I saw the following documentation on `lstat`:

```
lstat() is identical to stat(), except that if pathname is a symbolic
       link, then it returns information about the link itself, not the file
       that it refers to.
```

I don't exactly understand the implications of this, but maybe it relates to my issue?
So I decided to use regular `stat()` instead, and I still see the same problem.

**different compilers:** 
I've tried two different compilers with warnings and sanitizers.
`g++` and `clang++`.  Both exhibit the same problem.

**does it need compiled with a C compiler?**
I re-wrote the program in vanilla C (but still compiled it with g++/clang++).

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  printf("%d ",lstat(path_to_file, &fileInfo));
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}

int main(){

    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
}
```

All of a sudden, the problem is gone.  I start the program again and again quickly, but it always correctly reports that the directory is not there.
I switch back to the C++ code, and run my test again.  Sure enough, occasional false positives.

**Is it a system header?**
I put the C++ headers into the C version.  Program still works without problems.

**Is it std::cout?**
Maybe `std::cout` is slower, and that's why I'm seeing the problem... or maybe its completely unrelated.  Maybe using `std::cout` indirectly keeps something in the binary that's causing the problem.  Or is `std::cout` doing something globally to my program's environment?
I'm shooting in the dark here.

I tried the following:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  printf("%d ",lstat(path_to_file, &fileInfo));
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}

int main(){

    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
    printf("%d\n",Is_Directory("folder"));
}
```

Aha!

```
$./main
test
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
$./main
test
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
$./main
test
-1 1
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
$./main
test
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
$./main
test
-1 1
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
$./main
test
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
-1 0
```

Now its only the first check that sometimes returns true.
It's like `std::cout` is somehow messing up `S_ISDIR`, but after `S_ISDIR` is called, it does not mess up the next call to `S_ISDIR`.

**investigate source:**
I found the source code for `S_ISDIR` in `/usr/include/sys`:

```
/* Test macros for file types.  */
#define __S_ISTYPE(mode, mask)  (((mode) & __S_IFMT) == (mask))
#define S_ISDIR(mode)    __S_ISTYPE((mode), __S_IFDIR)
```

`S_ISDIR` seems to be nothing but a helper, and whether or not the directory exists, has already been decided from `stat()`.  (Again, I've tried both `stat` and `lstat`.  *Am I suppose to be using `fstat`?*  I don't think so.  I've found other examples online where people are using 
`S_ISDIR` in the same way as my example code).

Again, it doesn't show the symptoms when I put the code into an infinite loop of both checking and printing with `std::cout`.  Which leads me to believe the problem only occurs at the start of the program, but I guess that doesn't seem true either, because if you look at my original output, it went:

```
$./main
-1 false
-1 false
-1 true
-1 true
-1 true
-1 true
```

**operating system / hard drive / system libraries / compilers:**
Is there something wrong with my machine?
No, I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`.  I went and tried this on a different machine `CentOS 6.5` with an older version of `g++`.  Same results.
So my code is just bad.

**isolate the problem:**

I've simplified the issue.
This program will ***sometimes*** return an error.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  stat(path_to_file, &fileInfo);
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
int main(){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return Is_Directory("folder");
}
```

This program will ***never*** return an error.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  stat(path_to_file, &fileInfo);
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
int main(){
    return Is_Directory("folder");
}
```

Why would flushing a buffer result in a directory sometimes existing?
Actually, if I only flush the buffer, the problem goes away.

This program will ***never*** return an error.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
bool Is_Directory(const char* path_to_file){
  struct stat fileInfo;
  stat(path_to_file, &fileInfo);
  return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
int main(){
    std::cout.flush();
    return Is_Directory("folder");
}
```

Well, that's probably because it had nothing to flush.

As long as I flush at least one character, we have our problem again.
Here is the real MCVE:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << std::endl;
    struct stat fileInfo;
    stat("f", &fileInfo);
    return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
```

Again, an infinite loop does not work.
This program will ***never*** return (assuming it gets lucky on the first try):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    while (true){
        std::cout << std::endl;
        struct stat fileInfo;
        stat("f", &fileInfo);
        if(S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode)) return 0;
    }
}
```

So the problem arises when restarting processes as well as flushing?
I dumped the assembly, but it doesn't mean much to me.

```
g++ -std=c++1z -g -c a.cpp
objdump -d -M intel -S a.o > a.s

a.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   48 81 ec a0 00 00 00    sub    rsp,0xa0
   b:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
  12:   00 00 
  14:   48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
  18:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
    std::cout << std::endl;
  1a:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x0
  1f:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  24:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   29 <main+0x29>
    struct stat fileInfo;
    stat("f", &fileInfo);
  29:   48 8d 85 60 ff ff ff    lea    rax,[rbp-0xa0]
  30:   48 89 c6                mov    rsi,rax
  33:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  38:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   3d <main+0x3d>
    return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
  3d:   8b 85 78 ff ff ff       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x88]
  43:   25 00 f0 00 00          and    eax,0xf000
  48:   3d 00 40 00 00          cmp    eax,0x4000
  4d:   0f 94 c0                sete   al
  50:   0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
  53:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  57:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
  5e:   00 00 
  60:   74 05                   je     67 <main+0x67>
  62:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   67 <main+0x67>
  67:   c9                      leave  
  68:   c3                      ret    

0000000000000069 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>:
  69:   55                      push   rbp
  6a:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  6d:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
  71:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  74:   89 75 f8                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],esi
  77:   83 7d fc 01             cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  7b:   75 27                   jne    a4 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x3b>
  7d:   81 7d f8 ff ff 00 00    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xffff
  84:   75 1e                   jne    a4 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x3b>
  extern wostream wclog;    /// Linked to standard error (buffered)
#endif
  //@}

  // For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
  static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
  86:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  8b:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   90 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x27>
  90:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x0
  95:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    esi,0x0
  9a:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x0
  9f:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   a4 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii+0x3b>
  a4:   90                      nop
  a5:   c9                      leave  
  a6:   c3                      ret    

00000000000000a7 <_GLOBAL__sub_I_main>:
  a7:   55                      push   rbp
  a8:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  ab:   be ff ff 00 00          mov    esi,0xffff
  b0:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
  b5:   e8 af ff ff ff          call   69 <_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii>
  ba:   5d                      pop    rbp
  bb:   c3                      ret
```

I tried following the [stat](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/stat.c) source code, but got rather lost.
The C++ source code was a little easier to follow.  Here is the flush function from `/bits/ostream.tcc`:

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
    flush()
    {
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // DR 60. What is a formatted input function?
      // basic_ostream::flush() is *not* an unformatted output function.
      ios_base::iostate __err = ios_base::goodbit;
      __try
    {
      if (this->rdbuf() && this->rdbuf()->pubsync() == -1)
        __err |= ios_base::badbit;
    }
      __catch(__cxxabiv1::__forced_unwind&)
    {
      this->_M_setstate(ios_base::badbit);      
      __throw_exception_again;
    }
      __catch(...)
    { this->_M_setstate(ios_base::badbit); }
      if (__err)
    this->setstate(__err);
      return *this;
    }
```

It seems to call `pubsync()` which lead me to a `sync()` method in `/ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h`:

```
      sync()
      { return std::fflush(_M_file); }

      virtual std::streampos
      seekoff(std::streamoff __off, std::ios_base::seekdir __dir,
          std::ios_base::openmode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
      {
    std::streampos __ret(std::streamoff(-1));
    int __whence;
    if (__dir == std::ios_base::beg)
      __whence = SEEK_SET;
    else if (__dir == std::ios_base::cur)
      __whence = SEEK_CUR;
    else
      __whence = SEEK_END;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_LFS
    if (!fseeko64(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(ftello64(_M_file));
#else
    if (!fseek(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(std::ftell(_M_file));
#endif
    return __ret;
      }

      virtual std::streampos
      seekpos(std::streampos __pos,
          std::ios_base::openmode __mode =
          std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
      { return seekoff(std::streamoff(__pos), std::ios_base::beg, __mode); }
    };      sync()
      { return std::fflush(_M_file); }

      virtual std::streampos
      seekoff(std::streamoff __off, std::ios_base::seekdir __dir,
          std::ios_base::openmode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
      {
    std::streampos __ret(std::streamoff(-1));
    int __whence;
    if (__dir == std::ios_base::beg)
      __whence = SEEK_SET;
    else if (__dir == std::ios_base::cur)
      __whence = SEEK_CUR;
    else
      __whence = SEEK_END;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_LFS
    if (!fseeko64(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(ftello64(_M_file));
#else
    if (!fseek(_M_file, __off, __whence))
      __ret = std::streampos(std::ftell(_M_file));
#endif
    return __ret;
      }

      virtual std::streampos
      seekpos(std::streampos __pos,
          std::ios_base::openmode __mode =
          std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
      { return seekoff(std::streamoff(__pos), std::ios_base::beg, __mode); }
    };
```

As far as I can tell, C++ is farming the work out to `std::fflush`.

**After doing some more tests, I've discovered that
`fflush()` from `<iostream>` exhibits the problem, but `fflush()` from `<stdio.h>` does not.**

I attempted to trace backward from `fflush()`, but I think I hit the source code boundary.

```
   This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not
   marked with __THROW.  */
extern int fflush (FILE *__stream);
__END_NAMESPACE_STD

#ifdef __USE_MISC
/* Faster versions when locking is not required.

   This function is not part of POSIX and therefore no official
   cancellation point.  But due to similarity with an POSIX interface
   or due to the implementation it is a cancellation point and
   therefore not marked with __THROW.  */
extern int fflush_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
#endif
```

So it must be what I'm linking with?

```
//exhibits the problem
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    printf("\n");fflush(stdout);
    struct stat fileInfo;
    stat("f", &fileInfo);
    return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main a.cpp
ldd main
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdc878e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1300c00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1300837000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f130052d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bace4bc000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1300316000)
```

---

```
//works correctly
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("\n");fflush(stdout);
    struct stat fileInfo;
    stat("f", &fileInfo);
    return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
```

---

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main a.cpp
ldd main
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd57f7c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f482dc6c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055828633a000)
```

I assume `libstdc++.so.6` is not suitable for using `S_ISDIR`, but `libc.so.6` is?  Should I build the code that uses `S_ISDIR` separately and then link it with the C++ code? How would I be able to detect a problem like this sooner?  I still don't understand what's happening.  Am I trampling/observing the wrong memory because I linked the wrong libraries?  How would you go about resolving this?

Comment: You can only analyze the mode returned by `lstat()` if the system call succeeds.  If it fails, it returns `-1` (and it has probably not modified the data in `fileInfo` at all — though the values are indeterminate).  What you get in `fileInfo.st_mode` is garbage because the `lstat()` fails — it can return true or false for `S_ISDIR()` at whim.

Comment: If `lstat` returns -1 then you're running `S_ISDIR` against an uninitialized `struct stat`.

Comment: _"The error code of lstat is always -1 so I don't think there is an occasional error populating stat."_ Whoops.

Comment: _"The POSIX function S_ISDIR is occasionally lying to me. It's telling me that a directory exists"_ It's crucial to understand that this is not what `S_ISDIR` does. It doesn't tell you whether a directory exists. It tells you whether a file that has already been found on disk (via `stat`) is a directory. There is an important distinction! In your case the `stat` already failed, as shown by the -1s, so no file exists with that name... directory or otherwise.

Comment: There's probably a lot of stuff going on in your system while you run your program. It's not entirely impossible that some of what happens is creating directories or files...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only analyze the `struct stat` data set by `lstat()` if the system call succeeds.  If it fails, it returns `-1` (and it has probably not modified the data in `fileInfo` at all — though the values are indeterminate).  What you get in `fileInfo.st_mode` is garbage because the `lstat()` fails — it can return true or false for `S_ISDIR()` at whim.

Thus, your first example shows that `lstat()` fails every time, so any analysis of the `struct stat` is futile; it hasn't been set to any determinate value, and any result is OK.

The same argument applies to all the example code, I believe.

---

The difference between `stat()` and `lstat()` is that if the name provided is a symlink, the `stat()` system call refers to the file system object at the far end of the symlink (assuming there is one; it fails if the symlink points to a non-existent object), whereas the `lstat()` system call refers to the symlink itself.  When the name is not a symlink, the two calls return the same information.

Comment: Indeed. The effect of streaming `\n` or flushing the buffer or whatever is simply affecting that uninitialised memory as any UB may. I feel a bit bad for the OP, because that's a _lot_ of very diligent research/debugging gone into this problem, only to find out that they misread the manual, that they forgot error return code conventions, and that the very first assumption (that `-1` is an "ok" condition) doesn't hold.

Comment: Well, at least he learnt the very *first* rule of programming... https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I glanced at http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno and didn't see -1 in the list, which made me mistakenly think there was no error, and then I just went off the rails.  Thanks.

Comment: @TrevorHickey: The return code and the errno are two different things

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_dir( const char* path ){
    struct stat fileInfo;
    if( stat( path, &fileInfo) == -1 )
        return false;
    return S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode);
}
```

As others already pointed out `S_ISDIR` give correct results only if function `stat` succeded.
If `stat` fails, then `struct stat` will remain unchanged, and therefore in your example uninitialised, and therefore S_ISDIR(fileInfo.st_mode) will return garbage.
And `stat` will fail if path doesn't exist.

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.